# Find records where an attribute is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` model with the attributes `username`, `email` and `name`.

`username` and `email` are required upon signup, but not `name`.

What would be the query to find all users that have filled out `name` (i.e. it is no nil)?

The query should be at least Rails 3.2 and 4.0 compatible.

I'm thinking something in the lines of:

```
User.where(name: present?)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### present?

[`present?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L23) is essentially `not nil and not empty?`:

```
class Object
  def present?
    !blank?
  end
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
  end
end
```

### ActiveRecord condition

In Rails 4, *not conditions* can be done without raw sql code.

```
# Both lines lead to the same result:
User.where.not(name: [nil, ""])
User.where.not(name: nil).where.not(name: "")
```

Since there is no raw sql code, you don't have to worry about if they work with every database adapter. In fact, this works fine for both, mysql and postgres.

### to_sql

You can see how they translate to sql queries if you append `.to_sql`, for example in the rails console.

```
# rails console

User.where.not(name: [nil, ""]).to_sql
# => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE (NOT ((\"users\".\"name\" = '' OR \"users\".\"name\" IS NULL)))"

User.where.not(name: nil).where.not(name: "").to_sql
# => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE (\"users\".\"name\" IS NOT NULL) AND (\"users\".\"name\" != '')"
```

### Further Reading

- [1] [Rails 4 guide "ActiveRecord Query Interface"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.2/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)
- [2] [Definition of `present?` on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L23)

Answer (score 36):

[UPDATED 13/5/2022]

To get all records where an attribute is not present in SQL, we would write

```
WHERE attr IS NULL or attr = ''
```

an easy mistake to make is then to negate this and write

```
WHERE attr is not null and attr != ''
```

However in SQL this equates to writing

```
WHERE attr != ''
```

since the NULL value is always ignored when using the equality operator.

So this translates to rails as follows:

```
User.where.not(name: '')
```

[MY OLD ANSWER]

An empty value in a database gets a special value `NULL`. Testing whether is set uses the special comparator `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Then there still remains the possibility that an empty string was filled in, so a complete test would be

```
@users = User.where("name is NOT NULL and name != ''")
```

[UPDATED for rails 4+]

Since rails 4 we can write:

```
User.where.not(name: [nil, ""])
```

which will generate the same query. Awesome :)

Comment: nathanvda, copying my answer and adding it to yours it's not very polite

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: I apologise, but I originally answered this question in 2013, I am making sure the answer is still relevant, I am not sure what the etiquette is in referring to inspiration from others answers. But to be honest: the explanation on your answer was very confusing (not to say wrong).

Answer (score 12):

NOT SQL queries can be built by where.not

```
@users = User.where.not(name: nil)
```

Comment: I much prefer this approach as it works through the ORM.

With quoted queries, I'm always afraid the query won't work if my production database uses a different system than my local. (e.g. PostGres vs. SQLite)

Comment: `@users = User.where.not(name: "")` is useful as well if some have empty strings

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
User.where("name IS NOT NULL AND name != ?", "")
```

I edited my answer as per @nathavanda comments, which his answer in my opinion should be the accepted one.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `OR`? This seems like it would return an empty `name`, because it isn't `nil`.

Comment: I don't get the upvotes. This will not ignore NULL values at all.

Comment: For me this converts to the following sql `WHERE name != NULL` which is imho not correct. This always returns an empty set. It should be `WHERE name IS NOT NULL`. I am testing against Oracle and Postgres.

Comment: nathavanda, you are completely right. I had a misunderstanding on nil/null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```rb
User.where.not(name: '')
```

Because of the nature of `not`, it won't include records where `name` is `nil` nor empty string. See this [article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activerecord-s-where-not-and-nil) for more details about `not` and `nil`

Comment: This is a great answer. Your explanation however, is confusing to say the least: it is not because of `the nature of not` (imho implying the activerecord `not`) that this works, it works because SQL, when using comparison operators, will disregard NULL values. As I explain in detail in my answer.

Comment: @nathanvda ` will disregard NULL values` is equivalent to `it won't include records where name is nil`. Anyway, instead of copying it to your answer you could just have improved my answer by doing an `Edit`. This should have been the way to go.